# QDomEntity VS QDomElement| what is the difference between **QDomElement** and **QDomEntity**?

Tags: xml, qt

i am new to Qt Cpp programming
i want to use xml in QT. but there is some isues.
what is the difference between **QDomElement** and **QDomEntity**?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know QT but I guess it's using standard XML terminology where **element** is a construct like

```
<tag>content</tag>
```

and **entity** is a construct like

```
&nbsp;
```

(Technically `&nbsp;` is an `entity reference`, the entity is the corresponding declaration in the DTD that it refers to, so the way that QT uses the term may be a bit more subtle than this.)